# Qt's uic on mac os x can't find proper QtCore

Tags: macos, qt, cmake, qt5, uic

I am trying to build this guy https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/nexus/blob/master/INSTALL.md on my machine (Mac OS X 10.14.6). I am running into issue with Qt's uic.

I brew installed Qt5, version 5.12.3. I added it's bin folder to my $PATH.
When I run 'uic' in terminal, it fails with this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.12.3/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.12.3/bin/uic
  Reason: Incompatible library version: uic requires version 5.12.0 or later, but QtCore provides version 5.7.0
Abort trap: 6
```

I ran otool against uic and got this

```
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.12.3/bin/uic:
    /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.12.3/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.12.0, current version 5.12.3)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
```

So, it seems to me that my system might have another version of Qt somewhere and it's discovered first, but I don't know.

I looked into the System Information and found this

```
QTKit:

  Version:  7.7.3
  Obtained from:    Apple
  Last Modified:    11/30/18, 3:01 AM
  Kind: Intel
  64-Bit (Intel):   Yes
  Signed by:    Software Signing, Apple Code Signing Certification Authority, Apple Root CA
  Get Info String:  QTKit 7.7.3, Copyright 2003-2012, Apple Inc.
  Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework
  Private:  No
```

But this version doesn't match the version in the error. So, i don't think its this guy that is causing the issue.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue? I am not even sure where to begin with this.